# Can an apache module be installed and enabled without disrupting service?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've got an Apache 2 server running as a load balancer/proxy in production.

I'd like to install mod_headers, and restart the server - all without disrupting service in prod.

Is this possible?

I've seen [the docs here on Gracefully Restarting Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/stopping.html#graceful), but it doesn't say anything about installing new modules, and I wanted some "real world" feedback on how this tends to go.

Any thoughts?

Comment: enable the module in apache config file and after that, reload the service

Comment: hey... thanks for the feedback - i've done that before on toy sites, but wasnt sure it it *really* worked - ie did any clients have their service disrupted? I'm looking for real world feedback on whether or not this truly works.... thanks!

Comment: usually when you reload a service, the script of your service, implement one function reload and the body function, the scripts use kill -HUP, the kill -1 or kill -HUP tells to the running daemon to reload the configuration without stopping anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it can, just after installing `mod_whatever`, use following:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo service httpd configtest
Syntax OK
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ sudo service httpd graceful
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ echo $?
0
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```